# Regular Expression to search for a number between two

Tags: regex

I am not very familiar with Regular Expressions.

I have a requirement to extract all lines that match an 8 digit number between any two given numbers (for example 20200628 and 20200630) using  regular expression. The boundary numbers are not fixed, but need to be parameterized.

In case you are wondering, this number is a timestamp, and I am trying to extract information between two dates.

```
HHHHH,E.164,20200626113247
HHHHH,E.164,20200627070835
HHHHH,E.164,20200628125855
HHHHH,E.164,20200629053139
HHHHH,E.164,20200630125855
HHHHH,E.164,20200630125856
HHHHH,E.164,20200626122856
HHHHH,E.164,20200627041046
HHHHH,E.164,20200628125856
HHHHH,E.164,20200630115849
HHHHH,E.164,20200629204531
HHHHH,E.164,20200630125857
HHHHH,E.164,20200630125857
HHHHH,E.164,20200626083628
HHHHH,E.164,20200627070439
HHHHH,E.164,20200627125857
HHHHH,E.164,20200628231003
HHHHH,E.164,20200629122857
HHHHH,E.164,20200630122237
HHHHH,E.164,20200630122351
HHHHH,E.164,20200630122858
HHHHH,E.164,20200630122857
HHHHH,E.164,20200630084722
```

Comment: This is easy to do using a scripting language. If `str` were a variable holding the string in your example, the line of Ruby code, `str.split("\n").select { |line| (20200628..20200630).cover?(line[/(?<=,)\d{8}(?=\d{6}\z].to_i) }` would return an array containing 16 of the 32 lines, the first two being `"HHHHH,E.164,20200628125855"` and  `"HHHHH,E.164,20200629053139"`. The regex is demonstrated [here](https://regex101.com/r/DOQNFn/1/). If you must must match a single regular expression, yes, that could be done, but it would be a miserable job to code and test the regex generator needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the above data is stored in a file named data.txt, the idea is to sort it on the 3rd column delimited by the comma (i.e. sort -nk3), and then pass the sorted output through this perl filter, as demonstrated by this find_dates.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ $# -ne 3 ] && echo "Expects 3 args: YYYYmmdd start, YYYYmmdd end, and data filename" && exit

DATE1=$1
DATE2=$2
FILE=$3
echo "$DATE1" | perl -ne 'exit 1 unless /^\d{8}$/'
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "ERROR: First date is invalid - $DATE1" && exit
echo "$DATE2" | perl -ne 'exit 1 unless /^\d{8}$/'
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "ERROR: Second date is invalid - $DATE2" && exit
[ ! -r "$FILE" ] && echo "ERROR: File not found - $FILE" && exit

cat $FILE | sort -t, -nk3 | perl -ne '
BEGIN { $date1 = shift; $date2 = shift }
print if /164,$date1/ .. /164,$date2/;
print if /164,$date2/;
' $DATE1 $DATE2 | sort -u
```

Running the command `find_dates.sh 20200627 20200629 data.txt` will produce the result:

```
HHHHH,E.164,20200627041046
HHHHH,E.164,20200627070439
HHHHH,E.164,20200627070835
HHHHH,E.164,20200627125857
HHHHH,E.164,20200628125855
HHHHH,E.164,20200628125856
HHHHH,E.164,20200628231003
HHHHH,E.164,20200629053139
HHHHH,E.164,20200629122857
HHHHH,E.164,20200629204531
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example you gave, between `20200628` and `20200630`, you may try:

```
\b202006(?:2[89]|30)
```

### Demo

I might be tempted to make the general comment that regex is not very suitable for finding numerical ranges (whereas application programming languages are).  However, in the case of parsing a text log file, regex is what would be easily available.

Comment: Thank you Tim for your response. However, my problem is that both the min and max can be specified as parameters. 

You are right that Regular Expression are not most ideal in this case and I have to parse a log file.

Comment: @A4B4 If the values for which you want to search are dynamic, then you would either need a regex generating tool, or you would need to ask a new question.  Consider using one Stack Overflow question per date range to search in your log files.  I have answered your example.

Comment: I like your idea of generating the regex dynamically and will explore it.

Comment: That's a lot of work, you would have to build an engine of sorts...if you are an app developer, and need to parse log files, you would just type out the regex on the fly, as I have done above.